# Change of affiliation in manuscript under preparation

Tags: publications, affiliation

I have submitted a paper to a journal as part of my degree at university X. This paper includes my correspondence e-mail and affiliation to the laboratory at university X, of which my co-authors were a part.

I have now moved to another university in a different country and the paper has been returned with the reviewers' comments. Should I be updating my affiliation and e-mail, especially considering that the majority of the work (the submitted draft) was completed at my old lab? I'm not sure if this is important at all, or whether it has any implications for the eventual transfer of copyright.

Comment: Maybe contact the journal and ask their policy? It must happen very frequently.

Comment: Normally you add a note* *T. W. it is now at Institution

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing the revision work at the new place you can just add the new affiliation as a second one (e.g. with 1,2).

Yes, I would update the email as there is no point in a dead old one for anybody.

Answer (score 2):

The primary purpose of the affiliation is to give readers a way to contact you. As a consequence, you should update your affiliation at a point in the process where this is possible -- specifically, when you get the paper back for revisions.

If you continue to have an affiliation with your old institution, you can provide both affiliations with the paper. If you have severed your ties there but feel grateful for the time spent working there, you can note that in the acknowledgments.

Comment: *The primary purpose of the affiliation is to give readers a way to contact you.* University admins may disagree - from their point of view, the primary purpose of affiliation is to acknowledge the organisation which supported the researcher during the period when the research was done.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: Maybe. But then that's even more of a reason to switch te affiliation to the university you're currently at. Your old university *might like* it if you listed them, but you're under no obligation to them any more.

Comment: In a self-oriented model which treats all interactions as a game with finite resources and aims to optimise some functional of personal success, you may be right. And probably we should ditch all old friends and relations as soon as we are under no obligations to them. Frankly, many universities have turned into corporate institution and probably deserve such attitude. But not all which I've been to.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: Which is precisely why I would advocate thanking them in the acknowledgments.